# getting current latitude and longitude

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, cllocationmanager

I want to get current location, I see with this code but how can I assign to this latitude and longitude to label when click a button?

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation   *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    NSLog(@"latitudeAAAAA %f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude );
    NSLog(@"longitudeAAAA %f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    [corelocation stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf,%lf", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need set your own class as a delegate of the your `CLLocationManager` and then call`startUpdatingLocation` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW2)) to make it call the method you mention. The callback will come at some point after you've asked it to start updating location, and keep coming until you ask it to stop. You'll have to figure out for your use case if it should start by itself, but then only save the location (or what ever it is you want to do with it) when the user clicks a button, or if the updates should start when the user clicks (I'm not quite sure what you mean from your question).

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW2

Answer (score 0):

In the interface builder, set the `touchUpInside` event to call `- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender` (or set action programatically) then set your buttons delegate to self.  On `viewDidLoad` setup your `locationManager`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Button action:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%+.6f,%+.6f", locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button clicked" message:myLabel.text  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
    [alert show];

}
```

Location Manager delegate methods:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    NSDate* eventDate = newLocation.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (abs(howRecent) < 5.0) {
        NSLog(@"New Latitude %+.6f, Longitude %+.6f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    }
}
```